# Binary convert to string in Ruby

Tags: beginner, ruby, programming-challenge, converting

This was a challenge for [reddit #202 Easy /u/learnprogramming](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/2w84hl/20150216_challenge_202_easy_i_am_bender_please/) ...I wish that someone reviews my code and let me know your opinion about my way of thinking beacause I am a total beginner in Ruby:

```
class BinaryChar
  attr_accessor :binaryString

  def convertToChar
    binaryString.scan(/.{1,8}/) { |part| print part.to_i(2).chr }
    puts
  end

end

bc = BinaryChar.new
speak = 0 
loop do
  print "Enter string: "
  speak = gets
  bc.binaryString=(speak)
  bc.convertToChar
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BinaryChar` is a class with one method. You continually change the state of the object so you can call the method with the right "argument". That's not what classes are for, but module functions or class methods. I rewrote the code twice: once using a class in the right way and once using a module function (or class method).

**with a class**

```
class BinaryChar
  def initialize(string)
    @binary = string.scan(/.{1,8}/).map do |character|
      character.to_i(2).chr
    end
  end

  def to_s
    @binary.join
  end
end

loop do
  print "Enter string: "
  bc = BinaryChar.new(gets)

  puts bc # to_s is called automatically by puts.
end
```

**with a module function**

```
module Binary
  def self.to_binary(string)
    binary = string.scan(/.{1,8}/).map do |character|
      character.to_i(2).chr
    end

    binary.join
  end
end

loop do
  print "Enter string: "

  puts Binary.to_binary
end
```

A couple of minor nitpicks:

- In ruby the convention is to use `snake_case` for anything but `ClassNames` and `CONSTANTS`.
- When you get input from stdin (`gets`) a newline is appended to it (`"\n"`). In most cases you want to strip the newline of using `String#chomp`.
- Accessor methods can look just like variable assignments: `bc.binary_string = speak`.
- Conversion methods are usually named `to_<something>`. To convert to a `String`, for example, most classes implement a `to_s` method.

Comment: In your first example, you create a new object every time you get a new binary code from the keyboard. Isn't it a waste of resources? I thought exactly this - I created the object once (when the program runs) and then called the method who converts binary=>string every time. Also, what's the criterion for choosing between a class and a module ? What's the reason for using a "map" right there ?

Comment: I included the example to show how this would look like as a Class. It's not the most efficient, because, really, it's just a very thin wrapper around a function. A class generally carries some sort of state (in an `@instance_variable`). A module doesn't have state, it only has "class methods" which are basically just "pure" functions mapping some input to some output.

Comment: It's worth mentioning classes have other useful functionality. Typecasting, as demonstrated by 'to_s`, is a very useful feature. Comparison is another.